# Why does my angular app update result only if I resize my screen?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-components

I started using Angular and Reactive programming 3 days ago so I m new to this technology.

I have successfully implemented a spring boot backend server that will give me tweets by tag.

Now I'm trying to show for every received message on my flux an element to a list component in my angular app.

I'm successfully login to the console the search result but my `ngFor` is not working ... I don't know where I'm missing the good practice.

Here is my angular app implementation

My reactive twitter service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { ITweet } from './model/itweet';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ReactiveTwitterSpringService {

    tweetSubject = new BehaviorSubject<ITweet>(new ITweet);

    currentTweet = this.tweetSubject.asObservable();

    tweetTag: string;

    baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/search';

    search(tag: string) {

        const url = this.baseUrl + '/' + tag.trim().split(' ').join('_');

        return Observable.create(
            observer => {
                const enventSource = new EventSource(url);
                enventSource.onmessage = (message) => {
                    const json = JSON.parse(message.data);
                    console.log(new ITweet(json.tweetData.name, json.tweetData.text, json.tag));
                    this.tweetSubject.next(new ITweet(json.tweetData.name, json.tweetData.text, json.tag));
                    observer.next(new ITweet(json.tweetData.name, json.tweetData.text, json.tag));
                };
                enventSource.onerror = (error) => {
                    if (enventSource.readyState === 0) {
                        console.log('The stream has been closed by the server.');
                        enventSource.close();
                        observer.complete();
                    } else {
                        observer.error('EventSource error: ' + error);
                    }
                };
               return () => enventSource.close();
            }
        );
    }

    constructor() { }
}
```

My component where I have the search and the list of results:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakPointService } from '../../providers/break-point.service';
import { ReactiveTwitterSpringService } from '../../reactive/reactive-twitter-spring.service';
import { ITweet } from '../../reactive/model/itweet';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-tweet-list',
    templateUrl: './tweet-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tweet-list.component.css']
})
export class TweetListComponent implements OnInit {
    list_div_class;
    search_input_class;

    search_results: ITweet[] = new Array();
    subscribe: Subscription = new Subscription();
    constructor(private tweetService: ReactiveTwitterSpringService) { }

    search(tag) {
        this.search_results = new Array();
        this.subscribe.unsubscribe();
        this.subscribe = new Subscription();
        this.subscribe.add(this.tweetService.search(tag).subscribe(tweet => {
            this.search_results.push(tweet);
            console.log(tweet);
        }));
        console.log('array contains ' + this.search_results);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        BreakPointService.current_css.subscribe(value => {
            console.log('value is ' + value);
            this.setupCss(JSON.parse(value));
        });
    }

    setupCss(value: any): any {
        this.list_div_class = value.list_div_class;
        this.search_input_class = value.search_input_class;
    }
}
```

The html template related to my component:

```
<div class="{{list_div_class}}">
  <input type="text" class="{{search_input_class}}" (keyup.enter)="search(searchInput.value)" #searchInput>
  <ul class="w3-ul">
    <li *ngFor="let tweet of search_results ">
        data
      <app-tweet-detail [detail]="tweet"></app-tweet-detail>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm watching lot of tutorials but I don't know why I'm getting data on my console but not in my array? I feel that I'm using observables the wrong way, but to be honest I don't have understood them very well.

What am I doing wrong? And how to fix it ?

**Update**

Accidentally I resized my screen and the data was displayed, why?

here is images of my html content before and after resise

[image: before]

after

[image: after]

Thank you

For full project [github repository](https://github.com/MHTaleb/twitter_client)

Comment: How is the `w3-ul` CSS class defined?

Comment: I added the w3c style sheet in the index

Comment: OK. But what is the definition of the w3-ul CSS class? Post its code.

Comment: I dont know because it is part of this framework https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_lists.asp

Comment: So you're using a CSS class but you have no idea of what it does? Remove it. Disable CSS in your browser, and tell us what happens.

Comment: I removed all css from my project, the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular, We need to manually trigger change-detection by calling changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() or you can use subject/behavior subject with async observable.

**Approach 1:**

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){} 
this.subscribe.add(this.tweetService.search(tag).subscribe(tweet => {
    this.search_results.push(tweet);
    this.search_results = this.search_results.slice();
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    console.log(tweet);
}));
```

Approach 2:

```
public this.search_results$ = new Subject<any>();
this.subscribe.add(this.tweetService.search(tag).subscribe(tweet => {
    this.search_results.push(tweet);
    this.search_results$.next(this.search_results);
    console.log(tweet);
}));
```

Template:

```
<li *ngFor="let tweet of search_results$ | async ">
    data
  <app-tweet-detail [detail]="tweet"></app-tweet-detail>
</li>
```

Comment: That's incorrect. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kuseiy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: It's still incorrect. As my example shows, you don't need to manually trigger change detection. You basically never have to do that unless you explicitly disable automatic change detection.

Comment: We need to trigger in some cases, as we don't have the full codebase. If you tel don't need to trigger, then why ngFor is not working above?

Comment: It is working, since the OP does see the result once it resizes the page. It's most probably a CSS issue, which hides things under a given width (or above a given width).

Comment: it is not a css issue

Comment: have the same problem. And it is not a CSS issue. Part of my DOM is missing, until I resize. Running Angular 9, but it was the same for 6, 7, 8